# Try and except, need questions to not be random when erroneous data is entered

Tags: python, math

Its a maths quiz and in my try and except i need the same question to be repeated if erroneous or invalid data is entered but it gives a random.

Heres my code

```
import random

count = 0
score = 0
name = input("What is your name?: ")
print ("Hello",name,"welcome to the arithmetic quiz")

while count < 10:
  while True:
      try:
          num1 = random.randint(1, 10)
          num2 = random.randint(1, 10)
          operator = random.choice(["+", "-", "*"])
          print("What is: ", num1, operator, num2)
          user = int(input(" "))
          break
      except ValueError:
          print("That is invalid, enter your answer again: ") 

  if operator == "+":
                answer = num1 + num2
  elif operator == "-":
                answer = num1 - num2
  elif operator == "*":
                answer = num1 * num2

  if user == answer:
    print("Correct")
    score = score + 1
    count = count + 1
  else:
    print("Incorrect")
    count = count + 1

print(name, "You got", score, "out of 10")
```

Comment: Welcome to slashdot.  For future reference, try adding a language tag (in this case, Python) to your questions.  This is not really a question about math, but rather about programming.  Also, I *think* this will do what you want if you move the three `random` calls in your `try` block up to just before the inner loop.

Comment: @BrianMcFarland: Slashdot?  Eh, close enough... :)

Answer (score 1):

```
while count < 10:

    num1 = random.randint(1, 10)
    num2 = random.randint(1, 10)
    operator = random.choice(["+", "-", "*"])

    while True:
        try:
            print("What is: ", num1, operator, num2)
            user = int(input(" "))
            break

        except ValueError:
            print("That is invalid, enter your answer again: ")
```